# Jquery and coldfusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a page which needs to output results, i am using jquery with json to return and display the results but the results are not showing up in the relevant div which will appear when the user hovers over the relevant image. Here is the script below:

```
<style>
#normaldiv {}
.normaldiv {width:200px; height:200px; float:left; margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:15px; background-color:#CCC; position:relative;}
.hoverdiv {width:250px; height:350px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; top:-10px; z-index:10000; position:absolute; background-color:#FFF;/**/ margin-left:-25px;}
</style>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){


                var mydata  = eval({"COLUMNS":["SONG_ID","SONG_TITLE","SONG_DESC","SONG_ACTIVE","SONG_DATE","LINK"],"DATA":[21, "This Track - Original Mix (3:00)", "<p><strong>Artist: <\/strong>Me<br \/> <strong>Label:&nbsp;<\/strong>My Own <br \/> <strong>Genre: <\/strong>Country (<span class=\"trackTags\">Chilled<\/span>)<strong><\/strong><br \/> <strong>Release Date: <\/strong>2012-05-28<\/p>", 1, "May, 28 2012 00:00:00", "http:\/\/www.byme.com\/track\/this-track-original\/4356789", 161, 21]]})
                var output = document.getElementById('normaldiv');
            var colMap = new Object();

       //first - find my columnsco
        for(var i = 0; i < mydata.COLUMNS.length; i++) {
        colMap[mydata.COLUMNS[i]] = i;        
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < mydata.DATA.length; i++) {
        var str = " Title: " + mydata.DATA[i][colMap["SONG_TITLE"]] + "- Release Date: " + mydata.DATA[i][colMap["SONG_DATE"]] +  "Link: " + mydata.DATA[i][colMap["LINK"]] + "<br />" + mydata.DATA[i][colMap["SONG_DESC"]] + "<br />"+ "<br />";
            var title = mydata.DATA[i][colMap["SONG_TITLE"]] ;
            var reldate = mydata.DATA[i][colMap["SONG_DATE"]];
            var buynow = mydata.DATA[i][colMap["LINK"]];
            var reldesc = mydata.DATA[i][colMap["SONG_DESC"]];
            var relcov =  mydata.DATA[i][colMap["PHOTO_ID"]];
            output.innerHTML += "<div class=normaldiv>" + "<img src=images/rel/"+  mydata.DATA[i][colMap["PHOTO_ID"]]+".jpg width=200 height=200/>" +"</div>";
            var content = document.createTextNode(title);

        }   


            $(".normaldiv").hover(
        function () {
        $(this).append($('<div class=hoverdiv></div>'));
           }, 
        function () {
        $(this).find("div:last").remove();
                  }
                );
                });


</script>

<div id="normaldiv"></div>
```

Can someone tell me if the script is correct?
I have added a mocked up json data result.

I am getting the images to load in normaldiv but i would like the content to appear in the hover div when people hover over the image.

Thanks

Comment: give us a mocked sample of the JSON data

Comment: 21, "This Track - Original Mix (3:00)", "<p><strong>Artist: <\/strong>Me<br \/> <strong>Label:&nbsp;<\/strong>My Own <br \/> <strong>Genre: <\/strong>Country (<span class=\"trackTags\">Chilled<\/span>)<strong><\/strong><br \/> <strong>Release Date: <\/strong>2012-05-28<\/p>", 1, "May, 28 2012 00:00:00", "http:\/\/www.byme.com\/track\/this-track-original\/4356789", 161, 21

Comment: im going to edit post with a new script that i have done

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are serializing the results of a ColdFusion Query directly to JSON. While that works in terms of generating JSON, in my opinion, it makes it a huge pain to work with on the client because you end up with the awful COLUMN and DATA properties, that are a pain in the butt to work with.

I would create a better JSON object from CF ... one that looks like this when it gets to the client:

```
[
    {
        "song_id": 1234,
        "song_title": "My awesome song",
        "song_desc": "A description",
        "song_active": true,
        "song_date": "July 20, 2012 or whatever format you wish",
        "link": "http://stackoverflow.com"
    },
    {
        "song_id": 1235,
        "song_title": "My Other awesome song",
        "song_desc": "Another description",
        "song_active": false,
        "song_date": "July 18, 2012 or whatever format you wish",
        "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/again"
    },
]
```

This format will allow you to more easily loop over your returned JSON data and do the following in your client code where the data is returned from CFML (where mydata is the name of the returned JSON):

```
for(var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    var str = " Title: " + mydata[i].song_title + "- Release Date: " + mydata[i].song_date +  "Link: " + mydata[i].link + "<br />" + mydata[i].song_desc + "<br />"+ "<br />";
    output.innerHTML += str;
}
```

Again, that's just my preference about working with CF-generated JSON in the client and thought I'd throw it out there for you to consider.

Beyond that, it seems like you have a couple of missteps with the HTML elements (normal and hover divs). For example, normaldiv is not an ID, it's a class so getElementByID won't work. Also, you are adding an empty div class=hoverdiv when you hover ... when I think you want to be creating the hover div with the JSON data bby appending it. Following is a rewrite of the sample code that works (well, enough to maybe get you going!):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .normaldiv {width:200px; height:200px; float:left; margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:15px; background-color:#CCC; position:relative;}
    .hoverdiv {width:250px; height:350px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; top:-10px; z-index:10000; position:absolute; background-color:#FFF;/**/ margin-left:-25px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var mydata  = [
            {
                "song_id": 1234,
                "song_title": "My awesome song",
                "song_desc": "A description",
                "song_active": true,
                "song_date": "July 20, 2012 or whatever format you wish",
                "link": "http://stackoverflow.com"
            },
            {
                "song_id": 1235,
                "song_title": "My Other awesome song",
                "song_desc": "Another description",
                "song_active": false,
                "song_date": "July 18, 2012 or whatever format you wish",
                "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/again"
            },
        ]
        var output = $("<div class='hoverdiv'><\/div>");

        for(var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
            var str = " Title: " + mydata[i].song_title + "- Release Date: " + mydata[i].song_date +  "Link: " + mydata[i].link + "<br />" + mydata[i].song_desc + "<br />"+ "<br />";
            var title = mydata[i].song_title;
            var reldate = mydata[i].song_date;
            output.append(str);
            alert(str);
        } 

        $(".normaldiv").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).append(output);
            }, 
            function () {
                $(this).find("div:last").remove();
            }
        );
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="normaldiv"><img src="images/rel/161.jpg" width="200" height="200"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Craig, thank you for the reply, your code works great, thanks for your help. I would like to know how i can actually output the the coldfusion query to json like how you have done there?

Comment: Another think, how do i get it to display both results and not have the window load when the page opens?

Comment: For the CF, here's a link to a nice blog post on the subject: http://cfsimplicity.com/53/simpler-handling-of-json-serialised-coldfusion-query-objects

Comment: For the display, make sure the appropriate style is set to display: none and then, in the event handlers you can show/hide (.show(), .hide()) as required.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, appreciate it

Comment: i have managed to display all the images from the results, but when i hover over the results returned are only for one record which displays on all the hovers